# Is it possible to use ExcelJS in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, excel, react-native

I am trying to create an excel sheet from React Native mobile application. I have tried using [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to generate excel. But it is not supporting the styling excel sheet. Is it possible to use ExcelJS in React Native?

Answer (score 2):

First of all install the required modules (assuming usage of Expo):

```
npm install --save exceljs
expo install expo-file-system
expo install expo-sharing
```

Code example - Imports:

```
// Required to save to cache 
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
// ExcelJS
import ExcelJS from 'exceljs';
// From @types/node/buffer
import { Buffer as NodeBuffer } from 'buffer';
// Share excel via share dialog
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';
```

Code example - Function to generate Excel and return uri

```
// This returns a local uri that can be shared
const generateShareableExcel = async (): Promise<string> => {
  const now = new Date();
  const fileName = 'YourFilename.xlsx';
  const fileUri = FileSystem.cacheDirectory + fileName;
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    workbook.creator = 'Me';
    workbook.created = now;
    workbook.modified = now;
    // Add a sheet to work on
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('My Sheet', {});
    // Just some columns as used on ExcelJS Readme
    worksheet.columns = [
      { header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10 },
      { header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 32 },
      { header: 'D.O.B.', key: 'dob', width: 10, }
    ];
    // Add some test data
    worksheet.addRow({ id: 1, name: 'John Doe', dob: new Date(1970, 1, 1) });
    worksheet.addRow({ id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', dob: new Date(1969, 2, 3) });

    // Test styling - what OP wanted
    worksheet.eachRow((row, rowNumber) => {
      row.getCell(1).font = {
        name: 'Arial Black',
        color: { argb: 'FF00FF00' },
        family: 2,
        size: 14,
        bold: true
      };
    });
    
    // Write to file
    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((buffer: ExcelJS.Buffer) => {
      // Do this to use base64 encoding 
      const nodeBuffer = NodeBuffer.from(buffer);
      const bufferStr = nodeBuffer.toString('base64');
      FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, bufferStr, {
        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64
      }).then(() => {
        resolve(fileUri);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Code Example - Function to share generated Excel. Call this, for example, on the press of a button:

```
const shareExcel = async () => {
  const shareableExcelUri: string = await generateShareableExcel();

  Sharing.shareAsync(shareableExcelUri, {
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', // Android
    dialogTitle: 'Your dialog title here', // Android and Web
    UTI: 'com.microsoft.excel.xlsx' // iOS
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error', error);
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Return from sharing dialog');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with the help of Google spreadsheet and tabletop library. After searching a lot I found this way:

1. Install the tabletop library.
2. Upload your .xlsx file in google drive.
3. Now in select File -> Share-> Publish to web.
4. Once you click a new window open and your file published.
5. Now close this window and copy the key of your file.
   The Key will be found in the URL of the browser.

Forex:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/108O2Memo7yJ3-7fzngFSoulVj-J32vwcyLDu5Lslhik/edit#gid=1371815480

In the above URL: this will be the key "108O2Memo7yJ3-7fzngFSoulVj-J32vwcyLDu5Lslhik"
6. Now in your code pass this key to the init method of the tabletop.
7. Get data from the file and show it in the list.

Library install :
npm install tabletop

In component did mount I initialize tabletop.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Facts
    Tabletop.init({
        key: 'keyCopyFromUrl',
        callback: googleData => {
            this.setState({
                arrayFacts: googleData
            })
        },
        simpleSheet: true
    });
```

Now for showing this data

```
<FlatList
                            data={this.state.arrayFacts}
                            renderItem={this.renderItemFacts}
                            keyExtractor={(key, index) => index.toString()}
                        />
```

Comment: The OP mentions he wants to generate Excel, as with https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs. sheetjs does not support styling in the free version, thus OP wants to use ExcelJS to generate and style directly from their React Native app.